# Dotnet Core - How to dispose of RNGCryptoServiceProvider()

Tags: c#, visual-studio, roslyn-code-analysis

I am getting the warning:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Warning CA2000  Call System.IDisposable.Dispose on object created by 'new RNGCryptoServiceProvider()' before all references to it are out of scope. JobsLedger.AUTHORISATION    C:\Users\simon\OneDrive\Documents\1.0 - AURELIA\1.0 - JobsLedgerSPA -ASPNET CORE 3.1\JobsLedger.AUTHORISATION\CryptoService.cs  96  Active
```

The code this warning is occuring is on this line:

```
new RNGCryptoServiceProvider().GetBytes(salt = new byte[SaltSize]);
```

Its used as follows:

```
public string EncryptdatabaseName(string text)
        {
            byte[] salt;
            new RNGCryptoServiceProvider().GetBytes(salt = new byte[SaltSize]);

            using var aesAlg = Aes.Create();
            using var encryptor = aesAlg.CreateEncryptor(salt, aesAlg.IV);
            using var msEncrypt = new MemoryStream();
            using (var csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            using (var swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt))
            {
                swEncrypt.Write(text);
            }

            var iv = aesAlg.IV;

            var decryptedContent = msEncrypt.ToArray();

            var encryptedDatabaseName = new byte[iv.Length + decryptedContent.Length];

            Buffer.BlockCopy(iv, 0, encryptedDatabaseName, 0, iv.Length);
            Buffer.BlockCopy(decryptedContent, 0, encryptedDatabaseName, iv.Length, decryptedContent.Length);

            // Format hash with extra information
            return string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "$DATABASENAME$V1${0}${1}", Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedDatabaseName), salt);
        }
```

I am using Visual Studio 2019 and its the Roslyn compiler that is throwing this up.. I want to get rid of the warning..

How do I dispose of this?

Comment: Call `Dispose()` on `RNGCryptoServiceProvider` or wrap it in a `using` block. See doc for example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rngcryptoserviceprovider?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: I try to reproduce which code analyzers are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CA2000 means “Dispose objects before losing scope”. From [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/ca2000?view=vs-2019#how-to-fix-violations), you could try this code:

```
using(RNGCryptoServiceProvider test = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider())
{
   test.GetBytes(salt = new byte[SaltSize]);
}
```

If you want to suppress it directly, you could use this code, which is like:

```
#pragma warning disable CA1062
        new RNGCryptoServiceProvider().GetBytes(salt = new byte[SaltSize]);
#pragma warning restore CA1062
```